# MaxPool1d to be used to reduce number of channels

Tags: pytorch

I have a series of matrices outputted by Conv1d layers of dimensions B x 1 x L, I wish to turn them into B x 1 matrices through the application of what I (think) is the MaxPool1d function but no matter what padding or stride I try nothing works. What can I do? Am I supposed to be using 2d or 3d?

I have tried apply MaxPool1d but the output dimensions are only B x 1 x X s.t. X < L

Comment: You are trying the reduce the tensor along the last dimension `L`. You may use functions like `max`, `mean` or `min` which reduce array slices to scalars. In case of `MaxPool2d`, the window size (or the pool size) must equal `L`, but that would be a simple `max` operation performed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.